# Cassandra datacenters replication advanced usage

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, datastax

For a project, we use a Cassandra cluster in order to have fast reads/writes on a large number of (column oriented) generated data.

Until now, we only had 1 datacenter for prototyping.

We now plan to split our cluster in 2 datacenters to meet performance requirements (the data transfer between both datacenter is quite slow):

- datacenter #1 : located near our data producer services : intensively writes all data in Cassandra **periodically** (each writes has a “run_id” column in its primary key)
- datacenter #2 : located near our data consumer services: intensively reads all data produced by datacenter #1 for a given “run _id”.

However, we would like our consumer services to access data only in the datacenter near them (datacenter #2) **and** when all data for a given “run_id” have been completely replicated from datacenter #1 (data generated by the producer services).

My question is : how can we ensure that all data have been replicated in datancenter #2 before telling producer services (near datacenter #2) to start using them ?

Our best solutions so far (but still not good enough :-P):

- producer services (datacenter #1) writes in consistency “all”. But this leads to poor partitioning failure tolerance AND really bad writes performances.
- producer services (datacenter #1) writes in consistency “local_quorum” and a last “run finished” value could be written in consistency “all”. But it seems Cassandra does not ensure replication ordering.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Thanks a lot,

Fabrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no silver bullet to this issue.

We managed to use a single datacenter for our applications. We will use another one but as a backup and possibly in a downgrading manner.